# Test Framework quit unexpectedly, IntellijIdea, Java and TestNg test suite

Tags: java, intellij-idea, automated-tests, testng, ui-automation

I am migrating to Intellij Idea from Eclipse. I get the error shown in the image, when I run my test in Intellij Idea, but not in Eclipse. The tests run fine in Eclipse. Please tell me how to resolve this.

This is how I run the tests. The error I get:

[image: error]

Comment: This problem is [already being discussed in IntelliJ IDEA forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000104950-Test-Framework-quit-unexpectedly-java-testng-tests) between the user and JetBrains technical support. Once the root case is found, I'll add the response here.

Comment: @Abhishek Garg Alsongside, unless you share the details of what test, which testng version(in case trying to reproduce) and how you ran the test. Not much can be looked into.

Answer (score 1):

Invalidate cache and restart Intelli J, solved the issue for me.